# Fast alternative for Adobe Reader on Windows

Tags: windows

Can anyone recommend me a good alternative for Adobe Reader ? I need a software that is fast and light which works on Windows.

Comment: Google Chrome is the fastest I can think of without having any additional bells and whistles.

Comment: check Foxit reader (http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've been using [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) for a few years now. It was my replacement for Foxit reader when I became annoyed with that product for a few reasons (I won't go into it right now).

SumatraPDF supports various formats if you are looking for more than just a PDF reader. For example it supports:

> PDF, eBook (ePub, Mobi), XPS, DjVu, CHM, Comic Book (CBZ and CBR)

It runs on Windows and like Adobe Reader, it is free. It is also very lightweight (just under 10 MB once installed) and has a very fast startup time (less than a second for me, and rendering ebooks usually takes less than 3 seconds).

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of a PDF opened in SumatraPDF]

Comment: I'm curious. Why did end up annoyed by Foxit Reader?

Comment: If I recall correctly, it wasn't the product itself (I was quite happy with it; much better than Adobe Reader in my eyes). However, they sneakily added the Ask Toolbar in their installer (and updater, which is where I first got caught). Basically, they word it unintuitively forcing you to opt-out rather than opt-in. And it is done on a screen with check-boxes for everything except the toolbar (for that you had to click a decline button, which looks like you are declining installing foxit reader altogether). Small nuisance, but please don't try to trick me into installing it.

Comment: This was how it was a few years ago. It could have changed sinc ethen. And yes, I'm complaining about a good product I don't have to pay for. Still, it is a bit shady how it was done and I will look for alternative products when in that scenario. Found an old post that someone else noted the same issue: http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2010/06/29/foxit-updates-free-pdf-reader-to-v4-but-watch-out-for-adware/